Find complement of the union of two row spaces
Given two $\mathbb{F}_2^{N\times N}$ matrices with rank $N - 1$, I want to find the complement of the union of the two row spaces.
Example:
Let
$$A = \left [ \begin{matrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0
   \end{matrix} \right ]$$
$$B = \left [ \begin{matrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1
   \end{matrix} \right ]$$
I want to find a third matrix $C$, which has rank $N - 1$ as well, such that $RS(A) \cup RS(B) \cup RS(C) = \mathbb{F}_2$ with $RS$ being the row space of a matrix. Because all matrices have rank $N - 1$, all row spaces are subspaces of $\mathbb{F}_2^4$.
To find $C$, my idea was to find the complement of $RS(A) \cup RS(B)$, which should lead to $C$. Alternative ideas to find $C$, are also appreciated.
A matrix meeting these requirements is:
$$C = \left [ \begin{matrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0
   \end{matrix} \right ]$$
Thanks in advance!
Edit:
$RS(A) = \{a_1, a_2, ..., a_m\}$ This has dimension $N - 1$.
$RS(B) = \{b_1, b_2, ..., b_m\}$ This has dimension $N - 1$.
"Union" = $RS(A) \cup RS(B) = \{a_1, a_2, ..., a_m, b_1, b_2, ... ,b_m\}$, but not $\{a_1 + b_1, a_1 + b_2, ...\}$.
I am not sure what to call the union (as it is no subspace as @xxx said).
Now I want a third matrix C, such that with $RS(C) = \{c_1, c_2, ... c_m\}$,
$$RS(A) \cup RS(B) \cup RS(C) = \{a_1, a_2, ..., a_m, b_1, b_2, ..., b_m, c_1, c_2, ... c_m\} = \mathbb{F}_2^4.$$
Obviously I don't want the trivial answer, that C is the identity matrix, but rather a matrix with rank $N - 1$ as well.

The row space of (say) $A$ is not "part of $F_2$", it is a subspace of $F_2^4$.

@GerryMyerson thank you, i corrected my question.

@xxxxxxxxx Sorry if i expressed myself unclearly, math is not my primary field of research. How I understand it: The row spaces contain all the vectors which can be "formed" by a linear combination of the rows. So the union of those contains each vector formed by either of the matrices, but not of a linear combination of rows from matrix A and B. Now I am looking for the remaining vectors in $\mathbb{F}_2^4$, which are neither part of RS(A) nor RS(B).

@xxx, I would assume what's meant is the set-theoretic complement.

You still have the union of three row spaces being $F_2$, Honn.

@xxx, yes, I was careless. I should have said, a set containing the set-theoretic complement. A set whose union with the other two sets contains all of $F_2^4$.

@xxxxxxxxx Im sorry if I caused confusion. The union of RS(A) and RS(B) should have (and always has) dimension $N - 1$, so in this case dimension 3. My goal is to find a matrix C (with rank $N - 1$ as well), such that the union of all three row spaces has dimension $N$.

@xxxxxxxxx I added an edit to my original question, to hopefully make clear what I meant. Thanks for your help!

(Throughout, I am using $A$, $B$, and $C$ to refer to $N-1$ spaces instead of $N\times N$ matrices of rank $N-1$, since this feels more natural.)
By duality, there are precisely two inequivalent ways to select a third $N-1$ space $C$ given $A$ and $B$; either $C \cap B = A \cap B$, or $C \cap B \neq A \cap B$.
Note that $N-3 \leq \mathrm{dim}(A \cap B \cap C) \leq N-2$, while $\mathrm{dim}(A \cap B) = \mathrm{dim}(A \cap C) = \mathrm{dim}(B \cap C) = N-2$. So we can count the number of vectors covered by $A \cup B \cup C$ using inclusion-exclusion and see that in the first case, we cover
$$3\cdot 2^{N-1} - 3 \cdot 2^{N-2} + 2^{N-2} = 2^N$$
vectors, while in the second case we cover only
$$3\cdot 2^{N-1} - 3 \cdot 2^{N-2} + 2^{N-3} < 2^N.$$
So to get a matrix whose row space covers all of the remaining points, you need to compute a basis for $A \cap B$ to get the first $N-2$ rows, and select a point that is not in $A \cup B$ for the $(N-1)$st row (and of course the last row can be a zero row).
